# ARCPY loses Z when I use geometry WKB

Tags: arcpy, postgis, well-known-binary

I'm trying to convert a shape geometry to WKB within a arcpy.da.cursor for import it in a Postgis database. When I analyze the result I saw that arcpy give me a 2d geoemtry when I convert to WKB. 
Is there anyone who knows this problem??

Am I doing something wrong??

Comment: We can't tell what is going on without your code. Please [edit] the question to contain the relevant code snippet. You should also specify the *exact* versions of ArcGIS and PostgreSQL in use.

Comment: not sure this is an arcpy issue. If you look at this document, WKB only store X and Y (http://edndoc.esri.com/arcsde/9.1/general_topics/wkb_representation.htm). try using WKT (combined with ST_GeomFromText)

Comment: A 9.1 doc might not provide the best representation of the capabilities of ArcGIS 10.4/10.5. The WKB standard uses the same 4-dimensional coordinates as used by the Esri geometry processing library (with extras like collections, but without spatial references).